# change the first word multiple text files at once using python

Tags: python, file-handling

I have a lot of text files

I want to change their first word I tried this and it didn't work.
I want to read all the text files, open them and change the first word ( 8 characters ) to just one same phrase

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir("data"):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        content = filename.read()
        with open(os.path.join("data" , filename) , "w") as outfile:
            outfile.write("new word" + content[8:])
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "change.py", line 5, in <module> content = filename.read() AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: Is there an issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: There is curently no question here. I am guessing that this results in an exception. The exception is telling you what is wrong. It should be fairly understandable what it says, but if it is not, then you can ask what you dont understand.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution from my understanding of your question. Please, let me know if this is not the solution you seek.

```
import os



def fread(file):
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        f.close()
        return lines



def replace(file,folder):
    lines = fread(file)
    with open(file,'w') as four:
        
        for x in lines:
            print(x[0])
            s = x[0] # first word with n characters
    
            fout.write(x.replace(s,'your desired replacement'))
        fout.close()

    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    folder = "your folder containing files"
    curretndir = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(folder)
    for files in os.listdir(folder):
        if files.endswith(".txt"):
            replace(files, folder)
```

It would be nice if I knew the content of the file. depending on that you have to use .split() function if required. I am assuming your content is in the form:
word1 word2 word3 ...\n
wordn wordn+1 .... \n

Answer (score 0):

I have marked your mistake.

```py
import os

for filename in os.listdir("data"):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        with open(os.path.join("data" , filename),"r") as f: #<<-- you forgot to open the file like this
            content = f.read()
        with open(os.path.join("data" , filename) , "r") as outfile: #<<-- you are trying to read the file by using "r" change this to "w"
            outfile.write("new word" + content[8:]) #<<-- you are writing to the file
```

Comment: Same Problem : 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "change.py", line 5, in <module>
    content = filename.read()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: The error you are getting is trying to tell you that you are trying to apply `read` method on a `str` object. Look carefully... `filename` is just string...

Comment: when i used ur code i got 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "change.py", line 5, in <module>
    with open(filename,"r") as f: #<<-- you forgot to open the file like this
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'text.txt'

Comment: i change 
with open(filename,"r") as f:
to
with open(os.path.join("data" , filename) , "r") as f:

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir("data"):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        with open(os.path.join("data" , filename) , "r") as f:
            content = f.read()
        with open(os.path.join("data" , filename) , "w") as outfile: 
            outfile.write("new word" + content[8:])
```